# Send parameters from jade to js/node

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, leaflet

I am trying to pass variables from leaflet/jade to a js/node file.
I am using node + express + leaflet + js
I am doing it the following way but I am not getting the values.
Here is the code I am using:

app.js

```
var express = require('express');
var routes = require('./routes');
var tiles = require('./routes/tiles');
var http = require('http');
var path = require('path');
var app = express();
app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 3000);
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'jade');
app.use(express.favicon());
app.use(express.logger('dev'));
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded());
app.use(app.router);
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

if ('development' == app.get('env')) {
  app.use(express.errorHandler());
}

app.get('/', routes.index);
app.get('/tiles', tiles.tiles);

http.createServer(app).listen(app.get('port'), function(){
  console.log('Express server listening on port ' + app.get('port'));
});
```

index.js //the index file that renders the index.jade file

```
exports.index = function(req, res){
  res.render('index');
};
```

index.jade //the jade file, the line where I am sending the params is "tiles?z={z}&x={x}&y={y}"

```
doctype html
html
  head
    title Tile Server Example
    meta(charset='utf-8')
    meta(name='viewport', content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0')
    link(rel='stylesheet', href='http://cdn.leafletjs.com/leaflet-0.7.1/leaflet.css')
  body
     #map(style='width: 800px; height: 800px')
     a(href='tiles') < tiles >
    script(src='http://cdn.leafletjs.com/leaflet-0.7.1/leaflet.js')
  script.
    var map;
    var mbTiles = new L.tileLayer('tiles?z={z}&x={x}&y={y}', {
    tms: true,
    attribution: 'this is a test',
    opacity: 0.7
    });
    map = new L.Map("map",{
    zoom: 18,
    center: [12.83563,77.68312],
    layers: [mbTiles]
    });
```

tiles.js //here is where I get the params, I am displaying them via console

```
 var x = "", y = "", z = "";

module.exports = function(req, res){    
    x = req.query.x; 
    y = req.query.y;
    z = req.query.z;    

    console.log("z="+z+"&x="+x+"&y="+y);

    var sqlite3 = require('sqlite3').verbose();
    var db = new sqlite3.Database('routes/tiles.mbtiles');
    var sql = "SELECT * FROM tiles WHERE zoom_level = "+z+" AND tile_column = "+x+" AND tile_row = "+y;

    db.each(sql, function(err, row) {
            console.log(sql);
            res.writeHead(200, {'content-type':'image/jpg'});
            res.write(row.tile_data);
            res.end();
    }); 
    db.close();
};
```

Any idea?

Comment: Are values displayed in console when you log them?

Comment: You get this via console:
GET /tiles?z=16&x=46910&y=35126 - - ms - -

Comment: Well, it is just information about the request. I mean, does this statement: `console.log("x-->"+x);` log something? Or it is never reached?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to change, the way you export your modules. In `tiles.js`:

Change:

```
exports.tiles = function(req, res){ ...
```

To:

```
module.exports = function(req, res){
```

And in `app.js`:

```
app.get('/tiles', tiles.tiles)
```

To

```
app.get('/tiles', tiles)
```

**UPDATE**

Also, add `res.end()` after setting headers and needed information to change response into a finished state.

```
res.writeHead(200, {'content-type':'image/png'});
res.write(row.tile_data);
res.end();
```

Comment: I did the changes, and now loads the images, BUT, first time loads the page, the images are not displayed (log: GET / 200 394.741 ms - 619) and after one minute, tha page sends the params and loads the images (log; GET /tiles?z=16&x=46909&y=35123 200 120005.811 ms - -)

Comment: Oh, `120005.811 ms` is indeed too long. I think the problem is in mysql query. Can you log it to console, copy it and run it from mysql cli or some client? Would it take the same amount on time?

Comment: db is sqlite3 (file is renamed as .mbtiles and is indexed by zoom level, tile column and tile row). I run the query in SQLiteStudio and took 0.000 second(s).

Comment: Oh, i've missed that it is sqlite, sorry. One moment, I'll think about the issue.

Comment: Sorry, didn't have time to to do it. I'll try to bet back to this issue in the evening.

Comment: By the way, how nany rows query returns?

Comment: here is an image with a brief explanation, hope it helps: http://s3.postimg.org/r3ev74lv7/tiles.png

Comment: awesome! now works perfect!!! I have updated the original code and now it is fully funcional, so if someone needs it, they can take it and use it. Hats off and five stars for you my friend! Thank you very much for your time and help!! http://s11.postimg.org/xdfte8eib/tiles_ok.png